# Omitting certain data points in netcdf file using R

Tags: r

I have been trying to manipulate a netcdf file with 6 variables(let's name them 1,2,3,4,5,6), each having the dimensions (x,y,z,t). I want to omit all the rows of data where one of the variables(say variable 4) is greater than a certain value (say 10), and then perform some arithmetic functions using all variables.

Any input on the best way to do this?

I have been able to create a new variable where I omit the unneeded values of variable 4, but in doing so, it loses the grid information, and I am unable to perform further arithmetic on this file using variable 4. Is there a way to "reindex" this new variable to its old gird locations?

Should I replace all values of variable 4 > 10 with NA or something, and then manipulate the data?

Any suggestions/ideas would be extremely helpful.

I am not sure how to post a reproducible example for this data, but here is the output of open.ncdf(filename):

```
[1] "file clouds.ncf has 6 dimensions:"
[1] "TSTEP   Size: 240"
[1] "DATE-TIME   Size: 2"
[1] "LAY   Size: 1"
[1] "VAR   Size: 6"
[1] "ROW   Size: 299"
[1] "COL   Size: 459"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file clouds.ncf has 7 variables:"
[1] "int TFLAG[DATE-TIME,VAR,TSTEP]  Longname:TFLAG            Missval:NA"
[1] "float Augm3[COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:Augm3          Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float Atry [COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:Atry     Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float H2OT[COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:H2OT         Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float AS[COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:AS         Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float salt[COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:salt            Missval:1e+30"
[1] "float rain[COL,ROW,LAY,TSTEP]  Longname:rain   Missval:1e+30"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What package are you using? Please post a reproducible example with expected result.

Comment: Hi Roman. I have been trying to use the ncdf package. Sorry, I am not completely sure how to post a reproducible example for this data, but I have added the output of the open.ncdf function in my question. Thanks!